# Remove all characters of a string that are immediately followed by two vowels

Tags: c++, string

It is possible to delete all characters of a string that is immediately followed by two vowels, without the aid of a char array, using instead exclusively the "string" library ?

For example:

```
priamo -> iamo
```

The algorithm should be:

1. Cycling the string making a for loop from `0` to `string.length()-2` to prevent overflow
2. Compare pairs of characters with a char array containing all the vowels
3. Using "Erase" function in the string library to delete positions before the vowels

but I have no idea how to implement the second point without the help of an array of characters. Any suggestions?

Comment: [string::find will probably be your friend in this situation.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: Do you need to check again once some are gone? Consider aeee. The first pass would result in aee, and the second in ee.

Comment: @chris in `aeee` case , algorithm should give me `ee` erasing recursively the char before a pair of vowels, checking from the zero position

Comment: Well, sure, it's tricky to "compare pairs of characters with a char array" without using an array of characters. Where do these requirements come from?

Comment: @PeteBecker infact, i don't know how to make the exercise using only the aid of "string" library

Comment: @Tolga, you study so will be able to do it. as for the question, string has an erase method http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Comment: @Gir, yeah taking back my words, I interpreted the question wrong.

Comment: std::string essentially *is an encapsulated array of characters* an can be used as such

Comment: Library calls and continually copying down the string - just about the worst possible way of implementing this.  Luckily it's just an academic exercise <g>

Comment: So, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaa should become aa? That's easy to do: find the rightmost pair of vowels, and delete everything to the left of them. Which makes me think the problem isn't correctly specified.

Comment: I agree with Pete (I was going to say that). As the problem is specified, you only need to look for the last pair of vowels that are consecutive an extract from there to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find):

```
std::string s{"priamo"};
auto is_vowel = [](char c) -> bool {
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiou";
    return std::any_of(std::begin(vowels), std::prev(std::end(vowels)),
        [c](char d) { return c == d; } );
};
auto it = std::adjacent_find(s.crbegin(), s.crend(),
    [&](char c, char d) { return is_vowel(c) && is_vowel(d); }).base();
if (it != s.cbegin())
    s.erase(s.cbegin(), std::prev(it, 2));
```

Comment: They probably don't care, but this will do duplicate searches for each character in `s` to see if it's a vowel n-1 times.

Comment: You should use `any_of` instead of `find(...) != end`

Comment: @Dave nice, thanks,  About the duplicate searches - it's always good to leave room for performance improvement.  And the compiler might optimise it away.

Comment: Minor error in setting up the erase: the code checks that `it` doesn't point to the beginning of the string, then decrements it by 2. If `it` is equal to `s.cbegin()+1` this will produce a garbage value.

Comment: @PeteBecker it can't, though; `std::adjacent_find` will never return `prev(last)`.

Answer (score 0):

What they meant by saying **without the aid of char array** probably means that you must not do any kind of buffering. You can use `const char vowels[]="aeiou";` of course.

Well, this is probably wrong but should give you the idea and a base for others to correct:

```
string str="priamo";
const char vowels[]="aeiou";
size_t pos=0;
size_t vowels_piled_up=0;
while((pos=str.find_first_of(&vowels[0], pos+vowels_piled_up))!=string::npos)
{
  if((pos+1)+1 >= str.size())//break if it is on the last 2
     break;
  if((strchr(&vowels[0], str[pos+1]))!=NULL)
  {
     str.erase(vowels_piled_up, pos-1-vowels_piled_up);
     pos=0;
     vowels_piled_up+=2;
  }
  else
     ++pos;
}
```

Comment: in case `const char []` is unacceptable, `const std::string vowels("aeiou")` plays the same game

Comment: Note also that the definition of "vowel" depend on the language. "y" can be considered a vowel, as many other accented  versions, can be considered distinct.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia -- true, but for a beginner's exercise I don't think it's a good idea to add sophisticated locale processing. <g>

Comment: And I can see this does not cover a situation where 2 vowels directly come to front after an erase operation. i.e. priaeamo => ia **ea** mo => str.earse(2,-1).